# How to compress files using C# .NET 2.0?

Tags: c#, zip

I want to compress multiple files into a Zip folder.

I'm using C# .NET Framework 2.0, is it possible to do it without the use of 3rd party libraries?

I've tried System.IO.Compression but doesn't compress multiple files, just once.

Comment: Any reason why you use a .NET version from 2005??

Comment: @TaW Unfortunately I have due to some very outdated libraries used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. assuming you mean .Net *framework* 2.0, and not .Net *Core* 2.0. The [ZipArchive](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.compression.ziparchive?view=netframework-4.5) class you need to create actual zip files was added in .net framework 4.5. Earlier framework versions need to use a third party library. See [stack software recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/) for such libraries.

If you are on .Net Core 2.0, just use the linked ZipArchive class or the [ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.compression.zipfile.createfromdirectory?view=netcore-2.0)-method. If you are on .Net framework 2.0 I would *highly* recommend that you update. I do not think .Net framework 2.0 is preinstalled on any supported OS, and I do not think it is supported at all anymore. Updating to 4.8 should be fairly straightforward unless you use some really old and outdated libraries.

Comment: Thank you so much! Ended up using SharpZipLib.

Answer (score 0):

Could you not just do the zip compress with a foreach for all the files? something like this?

```
public static void CreateZip(string fileName, IEnumerable<string> files)
{
    var zip = ZipFile.Open(fileName, ZipArchiveMode.Create);
    foreach (var file in files)
    {
         zip.CreateEntryFromFile(file, Path.GetFileName(file), CompressionLevel.Optimal);
    }
}
```

Comment: Forgot to mention .NET Framework and not .NET Core 2.0, so I don't have ZipFile.